# Track any error occurred like Failed to load resource

Tags: javascript, browser, frontend

> Track failed resources

I am not sure, How I can track any error occurred like failed to load resource so that I can either load that resource manually or reload the page.

Please suggest me some options that I can do in Javascript.

Comment: How are you loading resources within `document`?

Comment: yes using <script> tag or templates for dialogs

Comment: Have you tried `script.onerror = function(){}`? What do you mean by "templates"?

Comment: Lets suppose I am using jqueryDialog for it i am providing template location . In that case what we can use to identify not loaded events

Comment: Not sure how you are implementing jqueryDialog. Can you include the `javascript` that you have tried at Question?